# linking my java layout object with xml layout in android

Tags: android

I have created an `LinearLayout` object in my .java file and tried to connect it with my .xml `layout` by using the following code,but it is not responding. Can you please explain to me why and what errors are in this code? I have named the `id` of the `LinearLayout` of .xml file as "root".

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView HelloWorldImageView = new ImageView(this);
        TextView t=new TextView(this);
        t.setText("hello");
        HelloWorldImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        l=new LinearLayout(this);
        l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
        l.addView(t);
        l.addView(HelloWorldImageView);
        setContentView(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? And why are you initializing `l` twice? Also, why don't you just put these `View`s in your xml? Then you don't have to initialize them with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

First off-  you don't need the `new` `LinearLayout` line.  The `findViewById()` will return an instantiated version.  Same for the the other newed `View`s.

Secondly-  you want to do a `setContentView()` before making any calls to `findViewById()`.  This way you set the `layout` (by passing it a `layout` `id`), Android will instantiate all the `View`s in your `layout`, and you can get references to them via `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this-

```
        setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);
        ImageView HelloWorldImageView = new ImageView(this);
        TextView t=new TextView(this);
        t.setText("hello");
        HelloWorldImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
        l.addView(t);
        l.addView(HelloWorldImageView);
```

You have to set that xml file in the setContentView() which has the root linear layout in it.

Comment: actually i was trying different methods thats why doing this.the problem was that it stopped working,but now,solved,i understood.thanks folks.